# Why いいます versus います?

Tags: word-choice

In Japanese 101 our textbook there is no explanation of why in some Japanese sentences there is “います” While in others there is: “いいます.”  Why is this or have I simply messed up and don’t understand?  It doesn’t make sense to me with my limited understanding of this beautiful language.

Comment: Those are two different words entirely

Comment: Does the textbook introduce the vocabulary before showing sentences? These are just two totally different words that aren't close in meaning.

Comment: Do you have sample sentences for each?

Comment: I didn’t realize these were two different words. Can someone tell me what these different words are?  Also here are two different sentences:  (please remember I’m very new to Japanese!)

Comment: Two different sentences:     ~はにほんごでなにといいますか。
~は日本語にほんごで何なにと言いいますか。
How do you say ～ in Japanese?

Comment: I see... just confusion about how kanji work, rather than います (いる) having anything to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

Your first example,

> Xはにほんごでなにといいますか,

is a well formed sentence written in hiragana. いいます means "to say", "to call" etc. The sentence means "What do you call X in Japanese".

Your second example,

> Xは日本語にほんごで何なにと言いいます,

is a confused mess. My guess is that you cut and pasted something with furigana, and the sentence was actually supposed to be

> Xは日本語{にほんご}で何{なに}と言{い}います。

Based on this assumption I think you are asking about the います in 言います. But います is not a separate word here. The full word is 言います and it is just the masu-form of 言う. To make the masu-form you replace the う with an い.

To labour the point, 言います and いいます are the same word. Just as the dictionary forms 言う and いう are the same. It's just that the first one is written with kanji in each case.

Finally います on its own is the masu-form of いる meaning "to be", "to exist" etc. That's why people are saying these are very different words.